# How do Wizards get their house colours?

Tags: harry-potter, clothing

In **Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone**, during the sorting ceremony, all the new students were wearing plain black robes with black ties. These were bought in *Diagon Alley* prior to their arrival at Hogwarts.

However, once classes begin, their robes are of course showing the colours of the houses they have been sorted into, complete with new ties and patches. Is it mentioned how this change occurs? Or are we simply expected to assume that it simply happened via some unspecified magic "off-screen" / "off-page" (in the case of the book)?

Comment: Is this a movie-only question? The coloured ties etc are from the films. The books have all the kids wearing the same black robes, regardless of house.

Comment: Because the movies are nonsense? In the books everyone just wears black robes and pointy hats.

Comment: @ibid It did wonders for me as a kid to remember which face is where. And to know "oh here come the baddies" etc. (the movies are still very non-sensical according to what I've read from answers here)

Comment: @ibid so tired of this 'movies are nonsense' bull. It's a visual art, you need to *show* things. Would you like an arrow above the chatacter 'Dean Thomas, a gryffindor' Draco Malfoy, a petty snake' like in the books? Would you like to hear HP monologuing in the middle of the great hall? Or for someone to read the books aloud on camera and call that a movie? Would you then be satisfied?

Comment: @D.O.B.Y2.0 - You have to remember that book snobs would have liked HP to be entirely faithful to the books, despite that meaning that it would have been seventeen hours long and totally unwatchable

Comment: @Valorum They **are** seventeen hours long and totally unwatchable. (OK, vicious circle but it had to be said...).

Comment: @TheDarkLord Of course *you* would hate the movies, but that's beside the point. The movies are going to take small visual liberties.

Comment: In light of the images confirming that their house colours are (most likely) presented to them on arrival, I was wondering if you might consider an acceptance. I doubt you'll find a better source than images from the film itself.

Comment: @Valorum Oh yeah, absolutely, have my acceptance :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the movie the first years are shown to Gryffindor tower. In the **very next scene** we see that their effects (neatly folded on the chairs beside their beds) now contain 1 x Gryffindor jumper, 1 x Gryffindor scarf, 1 x Gryffindor tie and 1 x pair of Gryffindor gloves.

Under the circumstances, and given the extreme similarity in how their new effects are laid out, it seems very likely that these items are simply issued by the school and were waiting for the student when they arrived in their dorm room rather than being purchased by the students from a school shop.

[image]

[image]

The badge (pictured below) is then presumably affixed to the robes using a simple [sticking charm](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sticking_Charm).

[image]

Comment: Gryffindor definitely seems like the house that would lay them out neatly on a bed. Slytherin  on the other hand might have a hazing ritual involved in getting them. But without evidence, we can't really say.

Comment: @corsiKa I doubt any of the students or staff would have been involved at all. This seems like the sort of work they'd leave to the House Elves, and they don't seem like the type to have hazing rituals.